# Flagging for questions in comments by a question-banned user (one or all)?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9109728/1105376) today...

In the comments I saw this:

> i cann't share my coding here . Becoz i has been blocked to ask
>   questions. tell me where do post the code. –

I don't think I've seen anyone try and work around a question ban in this manner before.  There follows a whole string of back and forth on this between the answerer and this commenter.

I flagged the first comment (custom flag explaining question in comments), should I flag them all?

Comment: http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100921030306/acecombat/images/a/a1/Flamethrower.jpg

Comment: Comment? What comment, you're imagining things... ;P (taken care of)

Comment: @pekka as a volunteer firefighter, I should disapprove, but I really want one of those!!  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just flag the first one for moderator attention, with an explanation. No need to flag each and every comment.

The moderator can then confirm if the user is question-banned and clean up.